# How to navigate by pages?

Tags: java, vaadin

I have a project in Maven, with Vaadin 8 framework using PostgreSQL.
I can't use Navigator class, because it doesn't work with spring boot.
How to make navigation in this project?

Answer (score 3):

If you use Spring Boot, it is recommended to use Vaadin Spring and Vaadin Spring Boot add-ons

https://vaadin.com/directory/component/vaadin-spring/3.1.1

https://vaadin.com/directory/component/vaadin-spring-boot/3.1.1

The add-on gives you SpringNavigator, which is modified version of Navigator which supports Spring.

When using Spring add-on you can use @SpringView annotation with the views, and they will be automatically registered in SpringNavigator, which you can easily just autowire.

There is more detailed documentation about the add-ons tand their use here

https://vaadin.com/docs/v8/framework/advanced/advanced-spring.html